# Exponents defaulting to Integer

Tags: haskell, ghc

I use `(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a` a lot to define constant factors or sizes. Problem is that GHC complains about defaulting to `Integer`.

Now I know why this happens ... and I know that I can "just" write `(x^(y::Int))` to get rid of the warning. But that looks just "ugly". Otoh living with the warnings is also not a great option.

Same thing applies for `(^^) :: (Integral b, Fractional a) => a -> b -> a` and `(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a` is not usable to me.

Anyone has a nice solution to this (first world) problem?

#### edit

Just found this gem of code:

```
alignment a = 2 ^ ceiling (logBase 2 (fromIntegral (sizeOf a)))
```

This is one LOC and GHC complains about defaulting to `Integer` and `Double` on the same line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define your own operator with a more specific type.  Or you could redefine the `(^)` operator with a more specific type, like this:

```
import Prelude hiding ((^))
import qualified Prelude ((^))

(^) :: Num a => a -> Int -> a
(^) = (Prelude.^)

x :: Int
x = 2^3
```

Comment: I do that a lot in my projects. IMO that should be the standard signature of `^` – there's almost never a need for exponents too large to fit in `Int`. In the cases where you have an exponent of a fixed other type given, you can generally use `fromIntegral` to get to `Int`.

Comment: Yeah ... I should probably do that too ... any recommendations on the actual sign to use? I wouldn't want the *Prelude hiding preamble* in every file.

Comment: It might be best to use NoImplicitPrelude and have a custom prelude for the project.  There's a good blog post about doing that [here](http://www.stephendiehl.com/posts/protolude.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want defaulting, you need the type annotations somewhere. An alternative to inline type annotations for places where they look too ugly are local definitions with signatures:

```
alignment :: Storable a => a -> Int
alignment a = 2 ^ (ceiling sizeLb :: Int) 
    where
    sizeLb :: Double
    sizeLb = logBase 2 (fromIntegral (sizeOf a))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some people explicitly type their literals in a single location.  I don't think it is the right solution for your case, the times I've seen it the issue was always Int/Integer ambiguity, but for the record:

```
two :: Int
two = 2
twoDbl :: Double
twoDbl = 2

...  two ^ blah
  where ...
    sizeLb = logBase twoDbl ...
```